# How to access .xlsx file stored on Sharepoint (with authentication) for Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, sharepoint, apache-poi

1. I have a .xlsx file stored on sharepoint, which requires login in order to get/see the excel file.
2. I need that file in order to do some ApachePOI operations on it
3. How to download that file?

I have tried doing it via InputStream but I don't know how to authenticate and I get 403 error which is obvious, as I don't provide password/login (don't know how)

```
InputStream inputStream = new URL("https://example.sharepoint.com/something/something1/file.xlsx").openStream();
Files.copy(inputStream, Paths.get("C:/file.xlsx"));
```

Is there a simple way to access that file?

Answer (score 1):

I would try `java.net.HttpURLConnection` together with `java.net.Authenticator` and `java.net.PasswordAuthentication`.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;

class ReadExcelFromURL {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
   private String username = "Domain\\UserName";
   private String password = "password";
   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    return new PasswordAuthentication (username, password.toCharArray());
   }
  });

  String stringURL = "https://example.sharepoint.com/something/something1/file.xlsx";

  URL url = new URL(stringURL);
  HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

  InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(in);

  for (Sheet sheet : workbook) {
   System.out.println(sheet); // success?
  }

  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.4.1</version> </dependency>

import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.auth.NTCredentials;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class SharePointClientAuthentication {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope(AuthScope.ANY),
            new NTCredentials("username", "password", "https://hostname", "domain"));
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .build();
    try {
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://hostname/_api/web/lists");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
```

Comment: If you need more help.. try this place... it has plenty of help for sharepoint... https://www.example-code.com/java/sharepoint.asp